# Import config file for use in javascript application with rollup

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I am using rollup and I have a js project set up like this:

```
- public
- src
  + components
  main.js

manifest.json
rollup.config.js
package.json
etc...
```

Standard setup. In `src/components/app/app.js` I would like to have access to the values in `manifest.json` - they are part of the project configuration. How can I achieve this?

Edit: It would be super nice to be able to do for example in `app.js`:

```
import config from 'config';

const routes = config.routes;
```

Comment: `import config from '../../../manifest.json';` should work according to app.js path you provided. Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @UsmanWali Yeah one of my plugins doesn't like it, complaining there's no available transformer for json

Comment: What node version do you have ? and can you share your package.json im just interested in your project dependencies btw.

Comment: 8.9.4 and I hardly have any dependencies

Comment: Update your node, I did had same issue long time ago and if I remember node update/or rollup update fixed it. If you dont want to update then `var config = require('../../../manifest.json');` is another option :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [rollup-plugin-json](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-json).

Comment: Straight from the source!